# I can't seem to declare variables within a pl/sql function?

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql

This is a really simple question, but I can't seem to find the syntax for this anywhere.

I have something like this:

```
FUNCTION some_function
(
t_string IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER IS

some_variable NUMBER;

BEGIN
//logic
END some_function;
```

It hits the some_variable declaration and tells me it was expecting "language" where/how do I declare variables? I've seen examples which have done it this way but for some reason it doesn't work.

Many thanks,
Fugu

Comment: Where do you run this? Create a database package with a definition and implementation part. Writing your function and calling it are two different things.

Comment: The declaration is fine. The problem has to lie in the body of the function.

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut: The declaration is not fine. Needs CREATE OR REPLACE.

Answer (score 6):

Did not found anything wrong with your declared variable:

```
create or replace FUNCTION some_function
(
t_string IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER 
IS
some_variable NUMBER;

BEGIN

return some_variable;

END some_function;
```

Returned NULL as expected:

```
select some_function('ff') from dual
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't have the CREATE OR REPLACE keywords in your function declaration, as shown in @Michael's answer.